# Removing all whitespace from a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, whitespace

How can I remove all newlines and spaces from a string in Ruby?

For example, if we have a string:

```
"123\n12312313\n\n123 1231 1231 1"
```

It should become this:

```
"12312312313123123112311"
```

That is, all whitespaces should be removed.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
var_name.gsub!(/\s+/, '')
```

Or, if you want to return the changed string, instead of modifying the variable,

```
var_name.gsub(/\s+/, '')
```

This will also let you chain it with other methods (i.e. `something_else = var_name.gsub(...).to_i` to strip the whitespace then convert it to an integer). `gsub!` will edit it in place, so you'd have to write `var_name.gsub!(...); something_else = var_name.to_i`. Strictly speaking, as long as there is at least one change made,`gsub!` will return the new version (i.e. the same thing `gsub` would return), but on the chance that you're getting a string with no whitespace, it'll return `nil` and things will break. Because of that, I'd prefer `gsub` if you're chaining methods.

`gsub` works by replacing any matches of the first argument with the contents second argument. In this case, it matches any sequence of consecutive whitespace characters (or just a single one) with the regex `/\s+/`, then replaces those with an empty string. There's also a block form if you want to do some processing on the matched part, rather than just replacing directly; see [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) for more information about that.

The Ruby docs for the class [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) are a good starting point to learn more about regular expressions -- I've found that they're useful in a wide variety of situations where a couple of milliseconds here or there don't count and you don't need to match things that can be nested arbitrarily deeply.

As [Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161878/gene) suggested in his comment, you could also use `tr`:

```
var_name.tr(" \t\r\n", '')
```

It works in a similar way, but instead of replacing a regex, it replaces every instance of the *n*th character of the first argument in the string it's called on with the *n*th character of the second parameter, or if there isn't, with nothing. See [`String#tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-tr) for more information.

Comment: `string.glub(/ /, '')` or `string.glub(' ', '')` works too.

Comment: @maguri Did you mean `gsub`? I don't know any method named `glub`. If you did, though -- That does work, but only if you're just trying to remove space characters (i.e. U+0020). If you're trying to remove _all_ whitespace, you need to add them in.

Comment: I meant to say `string.gsub(/ /, '')` or `string.gsub(' ', '')` yes, and I agree with you Nic.

Answer (score 10):

You could also use [String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-delete):

```
str = "123\n12312313\n\n123 1231 1231 1"

str.delete "\s\n"
  #=> "12312312313123123112311"
```

You could use [String#delete!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-delete-21) to modify `str` in place, but note `delete!` returns `nil` if no change is made

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could `scan` the string for digits `/\d+/` and `join` the result:

```
string = "123\n\n12312313\n\n123 1231 1231 1\n"

string.scan(/\d+/).join
#=> "12312312313123123112311"
```

Please note that this would also remove alphabetical characters, dashes, symbols, basically everything that is not a digit.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this can end up using quite a lot of memory if you have a very long list of numbers to remove whitespace from, since it first has to build an array of each occurrence, which it then joins. I think it's also a bit slower, since it iterates through twice, though I don't know about that.